# android (java) cannot get value from radiobutton by pressing button

Tags: java, android

Sorry I'm new here, this is my first post so sorry.

I want to get value from `radiobutton` by clicking button, but there is still an error there. why?

```
package com.example.jacobyogo.converter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class currency_conv extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editDollar;
    RadioButton radioRupiah;
    RadioButton radioSg;
    TextView txtResult;
    Button btnConvert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_currency_conv);

        editDollar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDollar);
        radioRupiah = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioRupiah);
        radioSg = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioSg);
        txtResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtHasil);
        btnConvert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);

        btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
                    switch(view.getId()) {
                        case R.id.radioRupiah:
                            if (checked)
                                converttorupiah();
                                break;
                        case R.id.radioSg:
                            if (checked)
                                converttosg();
                                break;
                    }
                }
            });
        };

    public void converttorupiah() {  
        double val = Double.parseDouble(editDollar.getText().toString());
        txtResult.setText(Double.toString(val*13000)); 
    }

    public void converttosg() { 
        double val = Double.parseDouble(editDollar.getText().toString());
        txtResult.setText(Double.toString(val*9000));
    }}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

in this line `boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();` view is your button, and casting it to a `RadioButton` is meaningless. You should use `radioRupiah.isChecked()` and `radioSg` wherever you need. Also
I think it would be better to do this instead of that switch case:

```
if (radioRupiah.isChecked())
    converttorupiah();
else
    converttosg();
```